# Problema com toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

https://jsfiddle.net/pkr6zeu2/2/

Eu estou com um problema no toggle button e não estou descobrindo o motivo, quando eu clico no btn-Help era para aparecer uma outra div help-body, mas não está funcionando.

Comment: atualiza o jsfidle com a função hide, vc nao colocou ela

Comment: Aqui apareceu o erro: `hideHelp is not defined`

Comment: vou arrumar pera ae

Comment: felipe? não tem vontade de usar jquery? vc faria tudo isso com um simples  $("nome_da_div).show()

Comment: poderia me mandar um exemplo manin?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pkr6zeu2/2/ atualizei está bem estranho ainda :(

Comment: eu estava querendo fazer um toggle bar no estilo desse do jsfiddle.

Comment: Vc quer em JavaScript puro ou jQuery?

Comment: tanto faz pow qualquer um dos dois eu só queria no mesmo modelo .

Comment: se tiver como da esse help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Melhor forma de fazer isso é usando `slideToggle()` ([mais info](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slidetoggle.asp)):

```js
$("#btnHelp").click(function(){
   $("#description").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.fundotog  {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 500px;
 background-image: url(../img/6.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-size: cover;

}
.togglefundo{
 width: 300px;
 height: 270px;
 background: #eee;
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-top: 60px;
 position: absolute;

}

.btn-Help {
 min-height: 59px;
 width: 300px;
 background-color: aqua;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  border: none;
 font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
 top: 0; left:0;

   z-index: 1;
}

.help-title{
 min-height: 50px;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top:0; left: 135px;


}
.help-title .h2{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 color: #ED0003;
 display: none;
}
.help-body{
 width: 300px;
 height: 0px;
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-top: 120px;
 background-color: #278C98;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: justify;
 border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;

}
.help-body p{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #000000;
 padding: 12px 35px;
}
@keyframes fadein-right{
  0%{ opacity:0; margin-left:45px;}
  100%{ opacity:1; margin-left=0;}
}
@keyframes fadein-bottom{
  0%{opacity:0; margin-top:45;}
  100%{opacity:1;margin-top:0;}
}
@keyframes fadeout-right{
  0%{opacity:1; margin-left:0;}
  100%{opacity:0; margin-left:45;}
 @keyframes fadeout-bottom{
   0%{opacity:1; margin-top:0;}
   100%{opacity:0; margin-top:45px;}
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
   <div class="fundotog">
      <div class="togglefundo">
         <div class="btn-Help" id="btnHelp">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="help-title" id="helpTitle">
         <h2 id="heading">Need Help</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="help-body" id="helpBody">
         <p id="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam eget ligula eu lectus lobortis condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla at risus. Quisque purus magna, auctor et, sagittis ac, posuere eu, lectus. Nam mattis, felis ut adipiscing.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Bro como eu faço pra abrir junto com o text do description uma borda de fundo?

Comment: @Felipe Como assim?

Comment: Tipo, ao clica no background azul,  descer um background junto com o texto.

Comment: @Felipe Ah tah.. perai um momento

Comment: @Felipe Veja se é algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/vje7uazc/

Comment: @Felipe É só botar um `background` no `.help-body p{`

Comment: isso mesmo mano vlww.

Comment: mano pode me dar uma ajuda? eu estou tentando dar um pequeno espaçamento entre as 2 div  o codigo: https://jsfiddle.net/oxf0r5gf/

Comment: com o br fica maior do q o espaçamento q eu queria e não tou conseguindo nem fodendo pelo css.

Comment: @Felipe Use margin-top ou padding-top

Answer (score 1):

> Como fazer um link, botao ou qualquer coisa que voce click mostre ou
>   oculte uma div

```
<a href="#" class="clickme">Click Me</a>

   <div class="box">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>

// Hide all the elements in the DOM that have a class of "box"
$('.box').hide();

// Make sure all the elements with a class of "clickme" are visible and bound
// with a click event to toggle the "box" state
$('.clickme').each(function() {
    $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
        // This is only needed if your using an anchor to target the "box" elements
        e.preventDefault();

        // Find the next "box" element in the DOM
        $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});


body {
    font: 12px/16px sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.clickme {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #666;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.clickme:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.box {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wGbh5/

Comment: Vlw mano do jeito q eu queria mandou mtt..

Comment: tamo junto mano, jquery é muito facilitador vale a pena aprender, sempre fiquei com receio de aprender novas tecnologias, mas tenho visto que vale a pena, no futuro quero aprender vue ou react dizem que é facilitador tambem

Comment: verdd mano, o codigo ficou bem pequeno e bem nice, vou começar a estudar j query realmente mt bom .

Comment: Opa julio tem como você me da mais uma ajudada? Cara eu tou tentando adicionar nesse codigo para qnd não deixar mais de 2 toggle buttons aberto ao mesmo tempo ou seja qnd abrir um o outro fechar, mas n tou conseguindo tem como dar uma ajduada?

Comment: usa o .is.(:visible) e faz um if